# Changing the parameters of background-image: url at runtime css

Tags: html, css

If I have url like :http://imageurl/image.jpg?w=160&h=160
Is there a way to specify the width and height parameters to background-image:url with the height and width of other div?

```
  .thumb{
        border:1px solid red;
        display:inline-block;
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
    }

    .thumbnail{
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image:url(http://imageurl/image.jpg?w=thumb.width&h=thumb.height)   
    }
```

Comment: You could use JavaScript

Comment: so its not possible with css?

Comment: You could achieve this by using a css preprocessor like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard css, that is static. So you would need javascript or a css preprocessor like http://lesscss.org/. So you could make the css dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using an actual image intead of a background-image and setting the image to use `object-fit: cover;`

```css
.thumb{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}
    
img.thumbnail{
   width: inherit; height: inherit;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x600" class="thumbnail">
</div>
```